# define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false); not working with WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm going to block WordPress core automatic updates.

I added the code: "define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);" in the wp-config.php file, before the sentence /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */, to disable automatic WordPress core updates.
Unfortunately, I noticed that WordPress has updated the core anyway.
I would like to ask if anyone has had the same thing happen to me and if I can have some pointers on the matter.
Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Please check your hosting panel and see if they manage the WordPress updates as well. Some hostings can manage the WordPress updates, and I am not sure if they respect `WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE` constant or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, unfortunately the site is managed at the company level on IIS servers and I don't know where to find a setting similar to the one you indicated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's becoming increasingly common for hosting compnanies to intervene and manage WordPress instances.

How that's handled varies from host to host but many of them have systems which recognise WordPress, keep it up to date, etc.

While you can set a config rule that tells WordPress not to self-update, that won't stop the hosting company's system from updating anyway.